# I am trying to delete every other element from a list, it is not working

Tags: python

```
def every_other (l):
    alist = []
    alist = l
    for i in range (len (l)-1):
        print (i)
        if i % 2 == 1:
            del (alist [i])
    print (alist)

every_other ([0, -12, 4, 18, 9, 10, 11, -23])
```

output is [0, 4, 18, 10, 11]
when it should be: [0, 4, 9, 11]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you delete something from a list, all the entries higher up get shifted downwards. If you want to do this, you could loop `i` downwards from the end instead of upwards from the start.

Comment: `del l[1::2]` should work without having a loop at all.

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove items from a list and iterate through it at the same time, because that confuses the iterator. Either create a new list and add to it instead of removing items from the old one, or you can use Python's slice syntax to do this in one operation:

```
def every_other(l):
    print l[::2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use list comprehension and filter the list based on its count:

```
the_list = [0, -12, 4, 18, 9, 10, 11, -23]

new_list = [i for a, i in enumerate(the_list) if  a%2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Below code will solve your logic:

 a=[0, -12, 4, 18, 9, 10, 11, -23]
 l=[]
 for i,x in enumerate(a):
     print "index : ",i,"data : ",x,">>>",i%2
     if i%2!=1:
         l.append(x)
```

you are deleting the same list that you are  trying to iterate.so when your are at index 1 you delete-12 your new list is [0,4, 18, 9, 10,11,-23]
now you reach index 2 of iteration your value is 18 so its not deleted and same  logic continues till the iteration completes.

Answer (score 0):

> This code should work if you only want to iterate every other element in a list;

```
def every_other(l):
       return l[0::2]
```

> But if you want to remove every other element then you should do that first before you print or return the list.

```
def remove_every_other(my_list):
     del my_list[1::2]
     return my_list
```